# Access or open database from external storage in android

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

--> Okay , here i have a Sq-lite database in SD card.

```
  (String DB_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().toString();)
```

--> Checking if database exists

```
        dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME );
        if(dbFile.exists()== true)
        {
            //set text db exists
            open_DB();

        }
        else 
        {
            //set text db does not exist
            return;
        }
```

--> on debugging i could confirm the existence of the database file. but when opening the
    database i get exception

```
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try 
    {
        dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbFile, null);

        //myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, 0);
        //also tried this

        //set text bd opened
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e) 
    {
        //set text bd unable open
        return;
    }
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is caused by flags or file so try to use this:

```
dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
if (dbFile.exists()) {
   db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(db_path, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
}
```

Let me know.